# mysql record and post record is same but not equal

Tags: php, mysqli, record

I´ve searched a lot but anything is not working for me.

I have a simple table in mysql:

```
id int 11                       //user id
log_meno varchar(255)           //user name
cmp_heslo varchar(255)          //user password
```

in this table i have one record:

```
id is 1
log_meno is kuki
cmp_heslo is 839512db1882dff3fcb596012982790870f6f06e   //it is hashed word kuki by sha1
```

than I have login form in html

```html
  <form action="login.php" method="post">
       <tr><td>Prihlasovacie meno: </td><td><input type="text" name="login_name" ></td></tr>
       <tr><td>Heslo: </td><td><input type="password" name="login_password"></td></tr>
       <tr><td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Prihlásiť"></td></tr>
       <tr><td colspan="2"><a href="#">Zabudnuté heslo</a></td></tr>
      </form>
```

and last i have login.php file

```html
<?php

include ('conn.php');

//Uzivatelsky vstup
$log_meno = mysqli_real_escape_string ($Conn, $_POST['login_name']);
$cmp_heslo = sha1($_POST['login_password']);  



$sql = "SELECT cmp_heslo FROM firmy WHERE log_meno='$log_meno'";
$result = mysqli_query($Conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {    
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo "$row[cmp_heslo]<br>$cmp_heslo";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}  



 if ($cmp_heslo == $row[cmp_heslo])
{
  echo "logged";
}
else
{
 echo "<br>bad password";
}     

mysqli_close($Conn);


 ?>
```

my problem is that $row[cmp_heslo] and $cmp_heslo is same but when i do action login I have this result:

839512db1882dff3fcb596012982790870f6f06e
839512db1882dff3fcb596012982790870f6f06e
bad password

why it is bad password i think that it should be logged. Sorry for my English and thank you for your answer

Comment: Instead of `echo` use `var_dump`. See how long the variables are. Maybe one has leading/trailing space. Your indexes also should be quoted `$row['cmp_heslo']`.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do:

```
$sql = "SELECT cmp_heslo 
       FROM firmy 
       WHERE log_meno='$log_meno' AND cmp_heslo = '$cmp_heslo' ";

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) { 
   echo "logged";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all, I´ve seen answer which solved my problem but when I reload page I can´t see that answer anymore. But that answer was to put my if else loop into the while loop. Thank you very much.

Comment: You refer to answer by @jbrya029 - but he deleted it ~1 hour ago.